# Error when connecting to mysql in Mamp

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I get this error when I try to connect to mysql database on phpmyadmin from nodejs . I am using same port number 3306 that is for mysql.After 4,5 seconds i get this error. I am using mamp free version for this .

> ```
> connect ETIMEDOUT at Connection._handleConnectTimeout
> ```

```
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var mysql = require('mysql');

    var app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

    //constants
    const STATUS_SUCCESS = "success";
    const STATUS_FAILURE = "failure";

    mysql
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : '172.0.0.1',
      user     : '****',
      password : '****',
      database : 'parking_application'
    });

    connection.connect();



    app.listen(4567,'localhost',function(){
      console.log("server started");
    });
```

Please Help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting? Is error reporting turned on? Also, do not post "real" user id/password/db name info in a public place like this.

Comment: Please Check https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1474

Answer (score 9):

```
    var mysql      = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    socketPath : '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock', //path to mysql sock in MAMP
    user : 'userdb',
    password : 'password',
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    database : 'yourdatabase'
});


connection.connect(function(err){
if(!err) {
    console.log("Database is connected ... nn");    
} else {
    console.log("Error connecting database ... nn");    
}
```

1. Add the socket MAMP path to mysql (mysql.sock) in the json object connection.
2. Restart your server.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be good to add a few lines of explanation to your answer.

Comment: Damn! It works like charm, I guess, socketPath, was it.

Comment: Worked for me too. Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

`172.0.0.1`. it's actually `127.0.0.1` or just use `localhost`